# Cyclic ORDER BY sorting in PostgreSQL

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I'm having a bit of an issue trying to sort in PostgreSQL. I want to select the info but order by a specific value passed to the query and it go from there. For example
say I have the following numbers.

```
31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25
```

I want to be able to say sort by `28` and the result will be,

`28, 27, 26, 25, 31, 30, 29`

I can't seem to get that to work I tried to sort it in PHP in the array and couldn't figure it out so I went the way of DB. Here is the query I tried.

```
<?php
    $sql_query="SELECT * FROM album_photos WHERE 
    alb_id=".$alb_id." ORDER BY CASE WHEN pho_id='".$pid."' 
    then 1 ELSE 2 END, pho_id DESC";
```

The reason I need this is because I need to order by the id that was clicked and so that fancybox(lightbox) will know which photo to start on and which will be the next and previous photos. Because the gallery is cyclic. 
Help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't see by which logic the remaining sequence (after the 28) `29, 30, 31, 25, 26, 27` is sorted

Comment: Maybe you need use 'union' to collect two sorted sets of numbers

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the logic is because I asked for it. :) I updated my question with the reason, but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: You can only order by values in a column (or columns) and you do so by telling the

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. How do you determine that 25 should appear *after* 31 but 29 *before* it? "*Order by the ID that was clicked*" does not make any sense. That's only a *single* value. How do you expect multiple values "sorted by" a single value?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the reason I gave random number because that might be the photo id of the persons photos. they are not always sequential it's what ever the database assigned them at the time they uploaded the photos. So they may only have 7 but stating at 25-31. Now does that make sense?

Comment: Sorry, still doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it's fine mvp got a great solution. thx anyway

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this SQL-only approach. Assuming that your numbers are stored in table as `(id, code)`, where `id` is serial (ordinal number 1,2,...) and `code` is 2-digit code as in your example, you can use this SQL to get desired ordering:

```
SELECT code
FROM mytable
ORDER BY id < 3, id
```

Where 3 is an example where start ordering in your table. This is [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0e243/3).

**UPDATE**: Explanation why this works: `ORDER BY` clause has 2 elements:
`id < 3` and `id`. First expression `id < 3` is of `BOOLEAN` type, and will be `TRUE` for first 2 elements and `FALSE` for others. Sorting by this criteria will make sure that first 2 elements will be 2 last elements of output, because `FALSE` < `TRUE`. Second sorting criteria `id` sorts normally.

In other words, input sequence of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 will be cycled to  3,4,5,6,7,1,2 on output.

**UPDATE 2**: If you only have one primary column, use this example to get your exact output: [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4ec3d/2).

Comment: nice solution - didn't know this possibility

Comment: Cool, but doesn't seem to be working for me. my table the `pho_id` is the primary id and first column. That the only row I want to sort by. What am I doing wrong? Use the 25-31 example I gave as the ID.

Comment: @Pjack: you can use your `pho_id` in place of `id` in my example. It should work. I will post SQLFiddle shortly...

Comment: Answer updated to give example exactly matching question: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4ec3d/2

Comment: I see why it's not working. UGhh!, The album is sorted newest image first(DESC), that's why your brilliant(and easy solution) is not working. That's why I also was trying to use DESC in my example but when typing out the 25-31 example I didn't write it in DESC order. Can this also work if the original order DESC. I really appreciate your time.

Comment: That works but not quite. it's cycling but the first number should actually be the number that is the variable. So for instance `$pho_id=28`, the result I want is `28,27,26,25,31,30,29` using the example it skips `28`. But it's almost what I need.

Comment: @Pjack: try using `<=` instead of `<`, like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4ec3d/4

Comment: Funny I just did that `id <= 28`. LOL and got it to work. Then I saw your comment. Great. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Like "test1604" described:

```
SELECT * 
FROM album_photos 
WHERE alb_id=".$alb_id." AND pho_id >='".$pid."'
ORDER BY pho_id
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM album_photos 
WHERE alb_id=".$alb_id." AND pho_id <'".$pid."'
ORDER BY pho_id
```

not tested...

Answer (score 0):

You can only order by values in a column: all values in that column. You do so by saying:

```
order by columnName [, columnName2, columnName3]
```

(with Name 2 and Name3 extra column names if you want to order by more than one column).

Your question has values from 25 to 31. Are these values in a column? If so then you can't do what you want. You can say e.g.

```
where columnName = 28
```

...but that doesn't seem to fit your question.

Is 28 a value in a column, or is it a column name? Only if it's a column name does what you want make sense. So you need to expand the info here, with e.g. a table definition and a requirement statement a bit more expansive that the one you've given.

Comment: I have now. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to do what you are after (assuming I understand correctly what it is):

```
select *
from album_photos
where alb_id=$alb_id
order by -sign(photo_id - ($pid - 1)), $pid
```

Comment: Yes, this is coming out random still. Not in the order it should

Comment: @Pjack It does work in my testing.  Provide your exact table structure and I'll test/match against it.

Comment: Thx for your help, mvp's final answer is working for me.